# Cannot complete LOAD DATA INFILE of large file in MySQL/Percona 5.7 VM

Tags: mysql, csv, percona

I recently migrated a database from a MySQL 5.6 physical server to Percona 5.7 Centos 7 VM.
In the legacy environment, the loading of a 27G CSV file into a single table took 2 hours to complete.
In the new environment, with heavily upgraded resources (RAM, CPUs, etc), it will run for over 24 hours and never complete.

Details:
Server CPU for the mysqld process will spike to over 100% when the job starts and maintain until the process is killed in db or command line.
This is a MyISAM table. (I do not want to hear about InnoDB. This engine is a customer requirement and there is no changing it)
Within 10 seconds, the MYI file for the table will build to 451MB and stop.  5 minutes later, it increases to 939MB within 5-10 seconds and stops again.  Up to an hour or two later, it will increase again to 1.6G.  24 hours later, it may reach 6.2G; but does not increase past that point.

Recall that during the 'quiet' times, CPU is at 100+%.  IO is zero except during the few seconds it is writing to the MYI file.  Server load is 1-2.  Memory usage is 27% at most.  Disk is SSD.  Server has 96G RAM.

The table is truncated before each script run, so bulk_insert_biffer_size is unused.  Keys are automatically disabled due to empty table.  I have tried tweaking every buffer and nothing changes the results in any way. I have changed the table to InnoDB, with no different except the files are a little bigger; but the stopping points are the same and it does not finish.

I have looked at OS level buffers and caching and have not found anything either.

Ideas?

```
    mysql> show global variables like '%buffer%';
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name                       | Value          |
+-------------------------------------+----------------+
| audit_log_buffer_size               | 1048576        |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size             | 67108864       |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size       | 134217728      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct         | 25             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename         | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances        | 8              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort       | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  | ON             |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now         | OFF            |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size             | 10737418240    |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size       | 25             |
| innodb_change_buffering             | all            |
| innodb_log_buffer_size              | 134217728      |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size             | 1048576        |
| join_buffer_size                    | 8388608        |
| key_buffer_size                     | 26843545600    |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size             | 4294967296     |
| net_buffer_length                   | 16384          |
| preload_buffer_size                 | 32768          |
| read_buffer_size                    | 1048576        |
| read_rnd_buffer_size                | 10485760       |
| sort_buffer_size                    | 67108864
```

Server Cores: 8 CPUs with 8 cores each

```
set sql_log_bin = 0;

LOCK TABLES t_surescripts_full WRITE;
TRUNCATE TABLE t_surescripts_full;
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/data/0149561_SS_PRE/SS_PRE_20200108_v44.match_output.just_output_records' INTO TABLE t_surescripts_full CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The processlist is not really helpful as the load data infile is the only query and its status is 'executing', even after 20 hours.

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 385429
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10240
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 10240
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    at 24 hours UPTIME of LOAD-DATA effort
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report before non-responsive. 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please post your LOAD DATA query.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE (myisam-engine); and for B) (innodb-engine);

Comment: Pastebin is not accessible to me. The table is quite large with 50+ columns but it the same as the old system used so that is not the issue.  Likewise, this is MyISAM so InnoDB storage engine details may not pertain.

Comment: ```Tasks: 225 total,   1 running, 224 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  8.0 us,  8.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 72.9 id, 10.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 98720768 total,   508800 free, 17809396 used, 80402576 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 76063208 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
18199 dbpenc    20   0   42.4g  16.0g   7656 S 117.9 17.0   9056:47 mysqld
 3887 dbpenc    20   0   56212   3296   2012 D  15.0  0.0  65:23.86 mysqldump
```

Comment: Posting the SHOW CREATE TABLE here would not be a strain on SO storage for 50 columns.

Comment: Could you gather B) C) D) from the above list and email as TEXT attachments to mydatalinks@mysqlservertuning.com?  Thanks.   You may want to reconsider the total absence of swap space.  RedHat suggests 20% of RAM unless hibernate is possible, then 120% for swap space.

Comment: Requested files sent.

Comment: Thanks, Need SGS and SGV with no \G, please.

Comment: Could you add SHOW WARNINGS; before you UNLOCK TABLES; in your script? Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE t_surescripts_full; ? Thanks

Comment: Sent new files.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these possibilities, please.

To set sql_bin_log OFF requires the user to have Super_priv as Y.

SELECT host,user,super_priv FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'somename'; 
may be used to confirm the super_priv is Y

SET sql_log_bin = 0;
might be more successful with
SET SESSION sql_log_bin = OFF;

to avoid logging 27G of CSV data being loaded.

Please post new time required and see email sent to you this AM for additional details.

Comment: My original posts shows that I had the binary logging disabled.  Also, this table is MyISAM, so it is unlikely that tweaking the buffer pool will have any effect.  This seems more like a CPU issue than anything else.

Comment: You asked for the binary logging to be disabled.  There was a version when the word OFF was required to get the bin logging disabled.  You may have that situation. With 96G of RAM and BP being refreshed 3 x per day, I would at least double the Innodb_buffer_pool_size. Any chance of getting 'Data We Need' from your 5.6 instance to compare? Some temp storage activities are cleared through Innodb_buffer_pool_size to get the job done.

Comment: @FloridaDBA Have you achieved your goals of loading data?  If any suggestions or comments helped, please upvote or accept so we know we helped with your situation, please.